# Catch ga event send failures

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I noticed the ga send calls will fail like when cookies are disabled
e.g. 
ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign');
Console will show 'Storage not available. Aborting hit.'

I tried using the callback 'hitCallback' but that gets triggered on success or failure.

How does one know if the http call actually went through or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Observing TASKS in analytics.js library

Analytics library has a few internal validating processed called tasks. If any of them fail, script throws abort and hit is canceled.

Tasks are:

- previewTask
- checkProtocolTask
- validationTask
- checkStorageTask
- historyImportTask
- samplerTask
- buildHitTask
- sendHitTask
- timingTask
- displayFeaturesTask

The most interesting task is **sendHitTask**.

### Tracker callback

We can pass a callback into **ga** tracker like this:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var originalHitTask = tracker.get('sendHitTask');   
  tracker.set('sendHitTask', function(model) {
    originalHitTask(model);    
  });
});
```

When validating task did not fail, the callback:

```
function(model) {
    originalHitTask(model);    
}
```

Is processed.

But if tracking fails, callback is not processed. So I try to detect this behavior wit setTimeout and setting tmp variable to true or false.

### Meta detection

```
ga(function(tracker) {
   var originalbuildHitTask = tracker.get('sendHitTask');
   var tmp = false;
     setTimeout(function(){
        if(tmp) {
            console.log("Success");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Failure");
        }
    },500);
  tracker.set('sendHitTask', function(model) {
    originalbuildHitTask(model);
    tmp = true;  
  });
});
```

### Working example

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {
  'cookieDomain' : 'bad.cxf', // set wrong domain, tracking will fail
});

// add task into tracker
ga(function(tracker) {
   var originalbuildHitTask = tracker.get('sendHitTask');
   var tmp = false;
   setTimeout(function(){
    if(tmp) {
      console.log("Success");
    }
    else {
      console.log("Failure");
    }
  },500);
  tracker.set('sendHitTask', function(model) {
    originalbuildHitTask(model);
    tmp = true;  
  });
});

ga('send', "pageview");
```

### Conslusion

This technique is definitely not the best, but the only one I have ever developed and found across internet. I will be very pleased if anybody will be able to improve it.

### Other possible solutions

**Detecting abort in analytics.js**

In decomposed analytics library there are methods throwing abort, so maybe there is posiibility to observe abort directly:

```
sc = function(a) {
        if (K(a[0])) this.u = a[0];
        else {
            var b = td.exec(a[0]);
            null != b && 4 == b[y] && (this.c = b[1] || "t0", this.e = b[2] || "", this.d = b[3], this.a = [][ha][C](a, 1), this.e || (this.A = "create" == this.d, this.i = "require" == this.d, this.g = "provide" == this.d, this.ba = "remove" == this.d), this.i && (3 <= this.a[y] ? (this.X = this.a[1], this.W = this.a[2]) : this.a[1] && (qa(this.a[1]) ? this.X = this.a[1] : this.W = this.a[1])));
            b = a[1];
            a = a[2];
            if (!this.d) throw "abort";
            if (this.i && (!qa(b) || "" == b)) throw "abort";
            if (this.g &&
                (!qa(b) || "" == b || !K(a))) throw "abort";
            if (ud(this.c) || ud(this.e)) throw "abort";
            if (this.g && "t0" != this.c) throw "abort";
        }
    };
```

And:

```
function Ja(a) {
    if (100 != a.get(Ka) && La(P(a, Q)) % 1E4 >= 100 * R(a, Ka)) throw "abort";
}

function Ma(a) {
    if (xa(P(a, Na))) throw "abort";
}

function Oa() {
    var a = M[B][E];
    if ("http:" != a && "https:" != a) throw "abort";
}
```

Another solution may be accessing certain Task and try to find some indications about aborting hit.